# Regular Expression Get part of the match

Tags: regex, notepad++

Good afternoon
In my timezone

I am using regular expressions in the Notepad++ to replace text.
I have the following snippet of text

```
sda4, sdas , asdas , asry , asdur , asdwb
```

I want to make the following replace

```
'sda4', 'sdas' , 'asdas' , 'asry' , 'asdur' , 'asdwb'
```

how is the best way to do it ?

Thanks in advance
Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you.
Find: `(\w{4,5})`
Replace: `'$0'`

This will surround any group of 4-5 alphanumeric characters with single quotes. If there is more than what you have specified it will not work.

If you need to surround any group of alphanumeric characters with single quotes you can use `(\b\w+\b)` which will match one or more alphanumeric character.

Comment: I'm impressed that you could understand the requirement

Comment: @ChrisLear I'm not sure I did to be honest.

Comment: The capture group is useless because you replace using `$0`. It will fail with string like `abcdefg,a1b2c3`

Comment: @Toto You're right. I was originally just trying to do a capture group for the small snippet that he needed. Wasn't trying to be broad.

Answer (score 0):

Find: `\s*([^,\s]+)\s*(,|$)\s*`

Replace: `'\1'\2`